# How do I clean up sensitive Node.js Buffers from Electron renderer process memory dumps?

Tags: node.js, angular, electron

I have a simple Electron test application that runs an Angular app in the renderer process. This angular app has two pages: Login and Account. After you log in using a username and password, you are redirected to the account page, where you can then log out.

**Login**

Component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html',
})
export class LoginComponent {
    password: string;
    username: string;

    constructor(private router: Router) {
    }

    submit() {
        let usernameBuffer = Buffer.from(this.username, 'utf8');
        let passwordBuffer = Buffer.from(this.password, 'utf8');

        // Do some Node stuff with the buffers...

        // Now done with the buffers. Clearing the properties like this
        // doesn't seem to help.
        usernameBuffer = null;
        passwordBuffer = null;

        this.router.navigate(['/account']);
    }
}
```

HTML

```
<form id="login-page" (ngSubmit)="submit()">
    <label for="username">Username</label><br>
    <input id="username" type="text" name="Username" [(ngModel)]="username" required><br><br>
    <label for="password">Password</label><br>
    <input id="password" type="password" name="Password" [(ngModel)]="password" required><br><br>
    <button type="submit">Log In</button>
</form>
```

**Account**

Component

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-account',
    templateUrl: 'account.component.html',
})
export class AccountComponent {
}
```

HTML

```
<p>You are logged in!</p>
<p><a routerLink="/login">Log Out</a></p>
```

**Test App**

If interested, full source code for this test app can be found here: https://github.com/kspearrin/electron-memtest . Just clone it, then run `npm i` and `npm run electron`.

---

Using Windows 10, after the user logs into the application and is on the account page, I can go to the task manager and perform a memory dump to create a .DMP file. Opening this .DMP file in Notepad, I can perform a search and see the username and password in plaintext.

In this test, I logged in with username "testusername" and password "testpassword-123".

[image: .dmp shows password]

This only happens if I create [Node Buffers](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer_from_buffer_alloc_and_buffer_allocunsafe) with the username and password data, as shown above in the `LoginComponent`. It seems like the Buffers are never released from memory. I thought that maybe the Node garbage collection just needed to eventually run, however, I let this application keep running all day long and the values are still there when creating new .DMP files. Maybe I need to force run garbage collection?

1. Why are these Buffers staying in memory?
2. How can I properly clean this sensitive data up?

Answer (score 0):

Zero [`fill`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buf_fill_value_offset_end_encoding) them:

```
usernameBuffer.fill(0)
passwordBuffer.fill(0)
```

Comment: Thanks. Do you know why these buffers are not being cleaned up automatically?